# How to install mobile app on device which is not listed on app's provisioning profile by using HockeyApp

Tags: ios, mobile, software-distribution, hockeyapp

Can we use HockeyApp to install mobile app on devices that are not listed in iOS app's provisioning profile?

Comment: As I know you need to build it with a developer profile not AdHoc, upload to HockeyApp and then open link in your device browser.

Comment: Thanks @RomanSimenok, I will try it